# C# EnumerateDirectories should not use localized paths

Tags: c#, file, directory, path

The code below produces following output:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programme` (Localized German)

**Problem**: These are both referring to the same directory but I can not call *EnumerateFiles* on the localized path (which wouldn't make sense anyway) because it produces an *System.UnauthorizedAccessException* and this also means I can not use *EnumerateFiles* with `SearchOption.AllDirectories` because I get the same Excepetion.

Is there a way to only get the functional non-localized paths out of *EnumerateDirectories*?

```cs
//Root Directory is C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
foreach(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo in rootDirectory.EnumerateDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dir: " + directoryInfo.FullName);
    //C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programme
    //C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
         //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recursively go through each directory so you can add an exception handler when you do not have access to a folder.  Below is an example of the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);
            
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
             

                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's definetly working this way even though it is not exactly what I want to achieve. Both of my example paths should actually be the same folder (e.x. also cmd says that only `/Programs` exists). I think there should be a solution to only get the actually Path out of EnumerateDirectories, GetDirectories, ..., because the localized Path doens't seem to exist in the first place.

Comment: Are you getting exception with first or second foreach?  I suspect you are getting exception with second foreach in your code.  Then you should be able to check the folder permission and not do second for each if you do not have access to folder.